Table input value not being stored to be retrieved outside of customtkinter table editing interface
I've build a dataframe editor that has an entry box at the top for someone to put their name in. I've tried several different ways to store the input into the "reviewed_by" variable, but it always returns blank, both inside and outside of the class. What could be happening here? How can I fix it?
class DataFrameEditor(ctk.CTk):
    def __init__(self, dataframe, corresponding_value, selected_month):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("Review Invoice")
        self.geometry("725x660")  # Adjusted window size

        self.dataframe = dataframe.copy().fillna(0)  # Replace NaN with 0
        self.entries = {}
        self.reviewed_by = tk.StringVar()

        # Add title rows to the DataFrame
        self.add_title_rows_to_dataframe()

        # Upper frame with logo, corresponding_value, selected_month, and reviewed_by
        upper_frame = ctk.CTkFrame(self)
        upper_frame.pack(fill="x", padx=10, pady=9)

        # Load and display the logo after the main window is set up
        script_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
        logo_path = os.path.join(script_dir, "logo.png")

        self.logo_image = Image.open(logo_path)
        self.logo_image = self.logo_image.resize((220, 50), Image.LANCZOS)
        self.logo_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(master=self, image=self.logo_image)
        
        logo_label = ctk.CTkLabel(upper_frame, image=self.logo_image, text="")
        logo_label.pack(side="left", padx=10)

        # Display corresponding_value and selected_month with reduced text size by 1
        details_frame = ctk.CTkFrame(upper_frame)
        details_frame.pack(side="left", padx=20, pady=10)  # Added padding

        # Program label and value on the same line
        program_label = ctk.CTkLabel(details_frame, text=f"Program: ", font=("Arial bold", 11))
        program_label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='w', padx=5)
        program_value_label = ctk.CTkLabel(details_frame, text=corresponding_value, font=("Arial", 11))
        program_value_label.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='w', padx=5)

        # Month label and value on the same line, below the Program line
        month_label = ctk.CTkLabel(details_frame, text=f"Month: ", font=("Arial bold", 11))
        month_label.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='w', padx=5, pady=(5, 0))
        month_value_label = ctk.CTkLabel(details_frame, text=selected_month, font=("Arial", 11))
        month_value_label.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='w', padx=5, pady=(5, 0))

        # Reviewed by text box
        reviewed_by_frame = ctk.CTkFrame(upper_frame)
        reviewed_by_frame.pack(side="right", padx=10)

        reviewed_by_label = ctk.CTkLabel(reviewed_by_frame, text="Reviewed by:", font=("Arial", 12))
        reviewed_by_label.pack(side="top")
        reviewed_by_entry = ctk.CTkEntry(reviewed_by_frame, textvariable=self.reviewed_by, width=200)
        reviewed_by_entry.pack(side="top", pady=5)

        self.frame = ctk.CTkFrame(self, fg_color="#302c2c")
        self.frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True, padx=20, pady=20)  # Center the frame within the main window

        self.table = ctk.CTkScrollableFrame(self.frame, fg_color="#302c2c")
        self.table.pack(fill="both", expand=True, padx=(30, 0))  # Keep the table as it was inside the frame

        self.build_table()

        button_frame = ctk.CTkFrame(self.frame)
        button_frame.pack(fill="x", pady=10)

        self.update_button = ctk.CTkButton(button_frame, text="Update", command=self.update_all_totals, fg_color="#5fa35f", width=100)
        self.submit_button = ctk.CTkButton(button_frame, text="Submit", command=self.submit, width=100)

        button_frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        button_frame.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

        self.update_button.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='ew')
        self.submit_button.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='ew')

        # Initialize reviewed_by_value to ensure it captures the input value
        self.reviewed_by_value = ""

    def add_title_rows_to_dataframe(self):
        # Create a list of tuples where each tuple contains a title and its insertion index
        title_rows = [
            ("Account Management", 0),
            ("Other Variable Fees", self.dataframe[self.dataframe['Item'] == "Documentation (additional B.U.s, brands, processes, etc.)"].index[0]),
            ("Warehouse Fees", self.dataframe[self.dataframe['Item'] == "Receiving minimum fee (Pallet / Sku)"].index[0]),
            ("Courier", self.dataframe[self.dataframe['Item'] == "Carrier Pass through Costs (Estimate, actuals will be billed) ATS ambient"].index[0])
        ]

        # Insert titles in reverse order to maintain correct positions
        for title, index in sorted(title_rows, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True):
            title_row = pd.DataFrame({"Item": [title], "RATES": [None], "MULTIPLE": [None], "TOTAL": [None]})
            self.dataframe = pd.concat([self.dataframe.iloc[:index], title_row, self.dataframe.iloc[index:]]).reset_index(drop=True)

    def build_table(self):
        for i, column in enumerate(self.dataframe.columns):
            label = ctk.CTkLabel(self.table, text=column)
            label.grid(row=0, column=i, padx=5, pady=5)

        for row_index, row in self.dataframe.iterrows():
            for col_index, value in enumerate(row):
                if pd.isna(value):  # Check if the value is NaN (title rows will have NaN values)
                    label = ctk.CTkLabel(self.table, text=row["Item"], anchor='center', fg_color="#4d4d4d")
                    label.grid(row=row_index + 1, column=0, columnspan=len(self.dataframe.columns), padx=5, pady=5, sticky='ew')
                    break
                elif col_index == 0:  # Item Description
                    label = ctk.CTkLabel(self.table, text=str(value)[:60], anchor='w')  # Display only first 30 characters
                    label.grid(row=row_index + 1, column=col_index, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='w')
                    self.table.columnconfigure(col_index, minsize=150)  # Set a minimum width for the Item column
                elif col_index == 1:  # Rates
                    label = ctk.CTkLabel(self.table, text=f"{value:.2f}" if value != 0 else "0.00")
                    label.grid(row=row_index + 1, column=col_index, padx=5, pady=5)
                elif col_index == 2:  # Multiple
                    entry = ctk.CTkEntry(self.table)
                    entry.insert(0, f"{value:.2f}" if value != 0 else "0.00")
                    entry.grid(row=row_index + 1, column=col_index, padx=5, pady=5)
                    entry.bind("<FocusOut>", self.update_total(row_index, entry))
                    entry.bind("<Return>", self.update_total(row_index, entry))  # Update on pressing Enter key
                    self.entries[(row_index, col_index)] = entry
                else:  # Total
                    label = ctk.CTkLabel(self.table, text=f"{value:.2f}" if value != 0 else "0.00")
                    label.grid(row=row_index + 1, column=col_index, padx=5, pady=5)

    def update_total(self, row_index, entry):
        def callback(event):
            try:
                item_description = self.dataframe.at[row_index, 'Item']
                print(f"Updating row: {row_index}, Item: {item_description}")

                if pd.isna(self.dataframe.at[row_index, 'RATES']):  # Check if the row is a title row
                    print(f"Skipping title row during update_total: {item_description}")
                    return

                multiple = float(entry.get()) if entry.get() else 0.0  # Ensure float and handle empty input
                rate = float(self.dataframe.iloc[row_index, 1])  # Assuming "RATES" is the second column
                total = round(rate * multiple, 2)  # Ensure 2 decimal places for "Total"
                self.dataframe.at[row_index, 'MULTIPLE'] = multiple
                self.dataframe.at[row_index, 'TOTAL'] = total

                # Update the corresponding labels in the table
                self.update_labels(row_index + 1, total)
            except ValueError:
                print(f"Error: Invalid input for 'Multiple' at row {row_index}")

        return callback

    def update_labels(self, row_index, total):
        for col_index, value in enumerate(self.dataframe.iloc[row_index - 2]):
            if col_index == 3:  # "Total" column
                total_label = self.table.grid_slaves(row=row_index, column=col_index)[0]
                total_label.configure(text=f"{total:.2f}")

    def update_all_totals(self):
        for (row_index, col_index), entry in self.entries.items():
            item_description = self.dataframe.at[row_index, 'Item']
            print(f"Processing row: {row_index}, Item: {item_description}")

            if pd.isna(self.dataframe.at[row_index, 'RATES']):  # Check if the row is a title row
                print(f"Skipping title row during update_all_totals: {item_description}")
                continue

            multiple = float(entry.get()) if entry.get() else 0.0  # Ensure float and handle empty input
            rate = float(self.dataframe.iloc[row_index, 1])  # Assuming "RATES" is the second column
            total = round(rate * multiple, 2)  # Ensure 2 decimal places for "Total"
            self.dataframe.at[row_index, 'MULTIPLE'] = multiple
            self.dataframe.at[row_index, 'TOTAL'] = total
            self.update_labels(row_index + 1, total)

    def submit(self):
        try:
            self.update_all_totals()
            # Remove title rows before saving
            self.dataframe = self.dataframe.dropna(subset=['RATES'])
            self.dataframe['MULTIPLE'] = self.dataframe['MULTIPLE'].astype(float).fillna(0)
            self.dataframe['TOTAL'] = self.dataframe['TOTAL'].astype(float).fillna(0)
            self.reviewed_by_value = self.reviewed_by.get()  # Ensure this captures the input value
            print("Updated DataFrame before closing the editor:\n", self.dataframe)
            print("Reviewed by (inside submit):", self.reviewed_by_value)  # Print inside submit method
            self.quit()
            self.destroy()
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error: {e}")

# Display the DataFrame editor for user input
app = DataFrameEditor(template, corresponding_value, selected_month)
app.mainloop()

updated_template = app.dataframe
reviewed_by = app.reviewed_by_value


I have a similar script that works fine in another implementation, using the same environment. Strangely, for the code I've posted here, I've had to change the way the logo.png is loaded by setting "master=self" - otherwise, it wouldn't recognize the file in the directory. I feel like that is related, but I'm not sure why the issue occured.

Try adding master=self inside the tk.StringVar().

That worked, thank you Lizzard
